# Which one goes first - Secant or Newton - in Numerical root finding technique?

Tags: mathematics, terminology

In Numerical root solving technique,  which comes first in history - Newton or Secant - and each one is named after whom?

Comment: Consult [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method), "secant method predates Newton's method by over 3000 years".

Comment: Browsing the text of the paper: J.M. Papakonstantinou, [Origin and Evolution of the Secant Method in One Dimension (2013)](http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/courses/Opt/reading.material.1/secant.pdf), things seems quite different.

Comment: Newton's method is a limiting case of the secant method.